# numberless pagination with non-granular sort order

Tags: sql, mongodb

I have a fast changing dataset and am implementing numberless next/prev navigation. The data is changing fast enough that numerical offset based queries are unreliable.  The traditional solution here is to offset the query based on the sorted field (eg: created_at > X). However, that doesn't work so well if the primary sort order isn't very granular. One thought I had is to do something like:

`... WHERE (nongranular = X AND granular > Y) OR nongranular > X ORDER BY ...`

However, I'm not quite happy with implementing the above pseudoquery in MongoDB: it's essentially 2 separate queries.

Is there a more elegant approach to implementing effective numberless pagination query when the primary sort is not granular but secondary sort order is granular?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MongoDB, you can use `_id: {$gt: last_bson_id}`. [The most significant bits of a BSON ID are a timestamp](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification), and the least significant bits are a serial number, resolving any granularity issues handily.

Comment: My primary sort order is not based on creation time but a (non-granular) field on the document. A simple $gt or $lt on that field isn't very useful, so I need to combine it with a secondary sort that is granular

Comment: Why not create a field on the document that is the combination of the nongranular and granular fields, in such a way that it'll sort appropriately, then sort on that field?

Comment: That would actually work very well. It also enables a simpler index